# Set Space between elements in JavaFX (Responsive window)

Tags: java, javafx

My target is to build a Window in Javafx where there are three buttons and a label.

1. Two buttons(1,2) on the left side will have 12px between them
2. Third button(3) will be on the right side of the window
3. And Lable will be the center of Button No. 2 and 3 (The text should be centered regardless of the window size)

This will be the expected output - [image: Expected Output]

My Code--

```
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("Advent Calender");

    Button button1 = new Button("Cheat");
    Button button2 = new Button("Regret");
    Button button3 = new Button("About");


    Label label = new Label("Placeholder for calendar");
    Label label1 = new Label("Advent Calendar 0.1 Alpha");

    HBox hbox1 = new HBox(button1,button2);

    HBox hbox2 = new HBox(label1);
    HBox hbox3 = new HBox(button3);

    hbox1.setSpacing(12);
    hbox1.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

    hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

    hbox3.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);


    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label,hbox1,hbox2,hbox3);
    


    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 800);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

> I was able to fulfill the first and 2nd condition however third one is the problem, when resizing the window label overlapping button (1,2)