# Setting size of cells in GridPane in order to fit the parent

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to make it so the objects/cells of a GridPane are made to fit the parent (TabPane in this instance)? I have been trying this using buttons inside of the GridPane for the past for hours and haven't been able to find a solution.

Here is what I've been trying:

```
GridPane gPane = new GridPane();
double size = Math.sqrt((tabPane.getTabs().get(0).getContent().getLayoutBounds().getHeight() * tabPane.getTabs().get(0).getContent().getLayoutBounds().getWidth()) / (rows * columns));
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                array[i][j] = new Button();
                array[i][j].setPrefWidth(size);
                array[i][j].setPrefHeight(size);
                gPane.add(array[i][j], i, j);
            }
```

When I run this, the size of the cells either don't match the size, or when they do, they do not fit the screen as they should.

Comment: See also [_Resizable Buttons in 4*6 GridPane_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855044/230513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a perfect scenario for using RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints to ensure your objects don't resize the gridpane.

From the Javadoc:

> By default, rows and columns will be sized to fit their content; a
> column will be wide enough to accommodate the widest child, a row tall
> enough to fit the tallest child.However, if an application needs to
> explicitly control the size of rows or columns, it may do so by adding
> RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints objects to specify those metrics.
> For example, to create a grid with two fixed-width columns:
>
> ```
>      GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
>      gridpane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(100)); // column 0 is 100 wide
>      gridpane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(200)); // column 1 is 200 wide
> ```

You can also size by percentage which may suite your needs better:

> Alternatively, RowConstraints and ColumnConstraints allow the size to
> be specified as a percentage of gridpane's available space:
>
> ```
>  GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
>  ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
>  column1.setPercentWidth(50);
>  ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints();
>  column2.setPercentWidth(50);
>  gridpane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1, column2); // each get 50% of width
> ```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: I saw something regarding that on another post. However, I didn't know whether I could use constraints while also continuing to use buttons?

Comment: The constraints don't impact what you can or can`t add to the GridPane, they just ensure that the sizing is correct/consistent.

Comment: Buttons are nodes, so they will resize according to constraints. By default buttons have their max size set to their preferred size, so if you don’t want that, [set their max size to MAX_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229149/javafx-automatic-resizing-and-button-padding).

Comment: Perfect, it works great. One minor issue: whenever I try to add cells of large values, in which there are more rows than columns (i.e. 40x10), the cells overflow the screen, if that makes sense.

Comment: Disregard, I found I had to set the buttons' min size to MIN_VALUE as well.